# Unable to access RabbitMQ admin page of RabbitMQ server running on a Debian Wheezy instance in Google Compute Engine

Tags: debian, rabbitmq, google-compute-engine

I'm using a Debian Wheezy instance on Google Compute Engine. I installed rabbitmq on the machine using:

```
sudo apt-get install rabbitmq-server
```

It shows that the server is running when I run the command:

```
sudo rabbitmqctl status
```

I then also installed the management plugin using:

```
sudo rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management
```

Also have uncommented the ulimit line in `/etc/default/rabbit-mq` server file and then restarted rabbitmq using `sudo service rabbitmq-server restart`

However, when I try to access the admin page using http://[my_machine_ip]:15672, it shows 'webpage is not available' message. I have also opened port tcp:15672 in the firewall for the network being used by the VM instance. Still, I'm unable to access the admin page.

Comment: From the VM running the admin frontend, can you run `telnet localhost 15672` and see the admin interface? If that doesn't work, you should fix it first. If it does, can you do the same from another VM on the same network, in the same GCP project, via `telnet [vm_name] 15672` and see if that works? Please add this information to your question. The issue could also be a firewall on the VM instance itself (you've already addressed the GCP firewall rule, but this is another one).

Comment: In some older versions of the server, you had to restart RabbitMQ after enabling a plugin, for the changes to take effect

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried using http://localhost:15672? Perhaps your machine is not allowing the traffic via the real IP... but it should work via `localhost` if the management plugin is running.

Have you run `rabbitmq-plugins list` and made sure the management plugin is running? You should see something like this:

```
[E*] rabbitmq_management               3.5.1
[e*] rabbitmq_management_agent         3.5.1
[E*] rabbitmq_management_visualiser    3.5.1
```

the `[E*]` means "Explicitly enabled"

Lastly, you may be running in to SELinux configuration issues. When I installed RMQ on Redhat Linux, I had to tell SELinux to allow the RMQ ports, including the web management port.

Comment: `sudo rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management` to enable